# Does the App Store approve Phonegap Apps

Tags: cordova, app-store

I am developing a simple to-do list app with PhoneGap. My app works offline, stores all data locally and uses iOS notifications. It can be used on a PC via web browser so I built it with HTML5.

Does Apple approve PhoneGap HTML5 apps for the App Store like my app? Should I use Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of Phonegap apps on App Store. And regarding your questions:

1. I wonder does apple approve phonegap html5 apps for appstore like mine app? : Yes Apple approves phone gap html5 apps. App will go through all the regular checks which apple does before releasing the application. So don't worry and go ahead.
2. Should I use objective c? : If your app requirement suits phone gap then you can go ahead and create app in phone gap. Objective C is not compulsory.

Answer (score 0):

There are thousands of apps already in app stores and directories. see http://phonegap.com/about/faq/#q_what_phonegap_apps_are_already_in_app_stores

Comment: I know but these apps are news readers or digital magazines. My app can work completely like a native app and doesnt need an internet connection. Does apple approve html5 apps that doesnt use web and acts like a native app. I read on a forum , apple doesnt like using html5 instead of objective c. I just want to learn procedure and dont want to be reject after completed my app.